# Coldfusion can't display proper JSON object

Tags: json, coldfusion

I'm developing web app using coldfusion. When client send a request to the app, the app needs to send response back with JSON object. So I'm trying to display JSON object but I'm getting two slash "//" before my JSON object. That's why when I use isJSON function, it returns NO.

Here is the code I'm using in coldfusion:

```
<cfset usr_result= StructNew() />
<cfset usr_result = {'result'='success', 'type'='new'}>
<cfset json = SerializeJSON(usr_result)>

<cfoutput>
  #json#
  #isJson(json)#
</cfoutput>
```

Output is:

```
//{"result":"success","type":"new"} NO
```

I'm expecting

```
{"result":"success","type":"new"} YES
```

Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to turning off the JSON prefix at the server level, you can turn off the prefix at the application level. In your application.cfc, you can add `this.secureJSON = false` to turn off the prefixing of the JSON string.

Answer (score 8):

Check the CF administrator. There is a setting labeled: `Prefix serialized JSON with`. Turn that setting off.

Comment: Thank you Scott! Is this only way to solve that issue? Because, I don't have a permission to login in to CF administrator.

Comment: You can strip the `//` off the string before you send it, or you can remove it on the client side when it is received.

Comment: I believe that will solve the issue too, but I used @Twillen 's solution. That was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: If you don't have access to the CF Administrator, why don't you find someone who does and get them to take the necessarry action?

Comment: Dan - That assumes it is a dedicated server. If not, the more granular application level setting may be more appropriate.